# Dynamically writing up to 5 select items, but want to limit to 5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

For my shopping cart I'm using a bit of javascript to update my select menu for a product amount to add to cart. It works great on updating on the fly depending on the stock left of a particular combination of 'S' in 'Red'. Though I'm trying to limit this select list of only 5, even if more then 5 is reported. Here is what I have thus far to rewrite the drop-down list:

```
<input type="hidden" id="store_product_stock" class="store_product_stock" />
<select name="item_qty" id="item_qty">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#store_product_stock').change(function() {
    // get the new stock level
    var stock = $(this).val();
    // remove existing dropdown options
    $('#item_qty').empty();
    // add dropdown options again
    for (var i=1; i <= stock; i++) {
      $('#item_qty').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: How would the above javascript be modified to limit the select menu to only 5 options of 1 - 5 if more then 5 is reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you not just force 5 when stock is over 5 like:

```
var stock = $(this).val();
if(stock > 5){
  stock = 5;
}
```

Comment: That was certainly easier then I thought. Worked like a charm. Thanks!